# Salesforce In - App Guidence

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment

Please let me know if there is any way to deploy the in-app guidance in the Salesforce by creating the package XML from the lower org to higher org.

In app guidance link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349069&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 2):

As linked in the documentation, the relevant Metadata API entity is [`Prompt`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_prompt.htm). The Metadata API's documentation includes a complete sample `package.xml` manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Prompt</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also deploy/retrieve individual members using just the prompt label (aka. the masterLabel field from the XML metadata) with all spaces and special characters stripped.  (Sorry, don't know what happens if you have two by the same name with just a special character difference.)

Example:

```
My In App Prompt v1.0
```

becomes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>MyInAppPromptv10</members>
        <name>Prompt</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```